# Convergence of a series with positive terms: $ \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {\frac{{a_n }}{{(a_1 + \cdots + a_n )^2 }}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a strictly positive sequence . How to prove that the series $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{a_n }}{{(a_1  + \cdots + a_n )^2 }}} 
$$ converges ? Any ideas ?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{a_n^2}$ is an upper bound.

Answer (score 6):

> Keyword: [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

For every $n\geqslant1$, let $A_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$, then, for every $n\geqslant2$, $A_n\geqslant A_{n-1}$ hence $$\frac{a_n}{A_n^2}\leqslant\frac{a_n}{A_nA_{n-1}}=\frac1{A_{n-1}}-\frac1{A_n}.$$ Summing these yields, for every $N$, $$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{A_n^2}\leqslant\frac1{a_1}+\sum_{n=2}^N\frac1{A_{n-1}}-\frac1{A_n}=\frac2{a_1}-\frac1{A_N}\leqslant\frac2{a_1}.$$ Thus, the series in the question converges and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{A_n^2}\leqslant\frac2{a_1}.$$

Comment: That's kickass :)

Comment: Nice one:) . I would have used comparison with integral, it can even give you the inf of {a;  $\sum \frac{a_n}{{S_n}^a}$ converges}

Comment: How can we get the value of the best possible constant $a_1$ ?

Comment: @Victor Sorry? Note that $a_1$ is given a priori, as every other $a_n$.

Comment: THAT'S EXACTLY WHAT I THOUGHT at first !!!I presented my calculus professor this interesting problem as well as your elegant solution.He then replied with the following question: 'If $a_1=1$ is $1$ the best possible constant to bound the series?If so why?Hint, think of Riemann sums.' The Riemann sum bit left me in the darkness completely..

Comment: @Victot The first term is $1/a_1$ hence the sum $S$ of the series is such that $1/a_1\lt S\leqslant2/a_1$. Multiplying every $a_n$, $n\geqslant2$, by $t\gg1$ makes that $S\to1/a_1$. Is this what you mean? (Riemann sums, slightly in disguise, are already at work in my answer (and your professor could have spotted that). Thus, one should not expect them to yield a better result.)

Answer (score 1):

First note that we can assume all the $a_n$ are at most $1$. If not, replace the term $a_n$ with $\lfloor a_n\rfloor$ copies of $1$ and a leftover $a_n-\lfloor a_n\rfloor$; this only increases the series.

Define $k(m)$ to be the least index $k$ such that $a_1+\cdots+a_k \ge m$ (with $k(0)=1$). Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(a_1+\cdots+a_n)^2} &= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k(m)}^{k(m+1)-1} \frac{a_n}{(a_1+\cdots+a_n)^2} \\
&\le \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k(m)}^{k(m+1)-1} \frac{a_n}{m^2} \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac1{m^2} \sum_{n=k(m)}^{k(m+1)-1} a_n \\
&\le \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac1{m^2} \cdot2 = \frac{\pi^2}3.
\end{align*}
The fact that $\sum_{n=k(m)}^{k(m+1)-1} a_n \le 2$ comes from the definition of the $k(m)$ and the fact that the $a_n\le1$.